# How to resolve this : "Error occurred during initialization of VM; Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to start my database server from command prompt in Windows. But I receive the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap

However the attempt is successful if I log off and log on again or restart. I think it is because of insufficient RAM in my computer (1GB).

How can I resolve this issue?

Please retag if I have tagged it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Java needs continuous address space/block to be reserved. If such a block can not be allocated by the system you get the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the memory settings of the VM. [see here](http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/java/-Xmx-settings) how to pass this as command-line arguments. For example

```
java -Xmx512m -Xms256m ....
```

If, however, your machines does not have enough RAM to handle this, the only resolution is to buy more RAM. It might still be possible to make it run with tweaking the above settings - I once spent half an hour trying to run an application with a limited amount of RAM by experimenting with different values for `Xmx` and `MaxPermSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the JVM an extra argument:

```
-mX256M
```

Despite the gigabyte of RAM in your machine, Java is only given a small chunk (64mb?) to play with. This argument allocates even more memory to the process.

Comment: In this case, he probably needs to decrease the minimum memory instead of increasing the maximum, since it looks like Java wants too much memory, and it isn't available. There is probably something like -Xms512M somewhere, and the system simply doesn't have that much free memory.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and resolved it by changing values in grade settings file of project

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
to
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m